# doInBackground error when using Jsoup in Android

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to learn Android and when I was trying to parse HTML by using Jsoup, I get an error and my app stops. I have a button in my layout and when I click it I want the app to update the TextView and write HTML Page's title. Here is the code (necessary parts):

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Title().execute(new String[] {url}); // I have url of an html address as a string above
    }
}

class Title extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {

    String pageTitle;

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
            pageTitle = doc.title();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return pageTitle;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute (String... params) {
        MainActivity.title.setText(params[0]);
    }

}
```

When I click the button, it says "Unfortunately, App has stopped."

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does the stacktrace say?

Answer (score 0):

try this in doInBackground() :

```
    { 
        String pageTitle;
        Element ele;
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                    t =doc.select("title");
                    pageTitle = t.text();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
           return pageTitle;
     }
```